# Getting Client ID and Secret for Teams App Portal-created Bot (REST API)

Tags: microsoft-teams, azureportal

I've created a REST API-based Teams Bot, and want to be able to receive and send messages. I added the Bot in Teams using App Portal, generated an App ID, messaging endpoint, and all that. I'm able to receive messages sent to the Bot. So far, so good.

My understanding from the docs is that in order to be able to send, however, I need a Client ID and Client Secret to get the access token for the header, and that the only way to get that is from within Azure Portal, creating a Bot Channels Registration. When I do that, and enter the App ID and password I created in the Teams App Portal, Azure Portal's Bot Channels Registration doesn't find the App.

(I tried using the app ID and password I got through the App Portal in Teams to get the access token, but got an authentication error.)

How can I get the authentication credentials to be able to send REST API messages to the bot?

Comment: Check this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-bot-aad) and [Sample Code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-auth-node/blob/e84020562d7c8b83f4a357a4a4d91298c5d2989d/src/dialogs/BaseIdentityDialog.ts#L154-L195). This sample code will help you set up authentication step by step.

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT That seems to be focused on OAuth, which assumes (a) user-based authentication, and (b) is based on Node. Neither is true here. Rather, it would seem the more appropriate model is JWT, as described in the [Microsoft document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). But that doesn't solve the left-hand-doesn't-see-the-right-hand problem.

Comment: @squarelines You could get the bot id and password from the portal where you created the bot. What error are you getting while doing Authentication?